# Is it necessary to call `yield break` after loop?

Tags: c#

In my code i have a method like this

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetDiff(int start, int end)
{
    while (start < end)
    {
        yield return start;
            start++;
    }
    yield break; // do we need to call it explicitly?
}
```

So, the test cases i'm interested in are `GetDiff(1, 5)` and `GetDiff(5, 1)`. While it's clear what happen in the first case, it's not quite clear how it get finished in the second without `yield break;` after loop

Comment: no. who taught you that? what do you mean "how it get finished"? it simply goes to the end of procedure

Comment: yield break is like a thread reaching the end of its function and terminating.

Comment: @Frenchy Eh? `yield break;` is like `break;` in a `for` loop.

Comment: @john, when you use yield you use a generator will could never stop. yield break stop the generator.. and doesnt return value..

Comment: but its not necessary...

Comment: @French I don't really follow you. Why would it never stop? The only scenario where it "could never stop" is an infintie loop. Placing `yield break` afterward the loop wouldn't help you in that scenario.

Comment: @Adassko, the main point of this answer is that all branches of your non-void method should return the value. Obviously it's non-void method, but for some reasons (explained in Theraot's response) it's not necessary to put break statement here, because of compiler do it for you (return false in MoveNext method).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No this is not necessary. It will work:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetDiff(int start, int end)
{
    while (start < end)
    {
        yield return start;
        start++;
    }
    // yield break; - It is not necessary. It is like `return` which does not return a value.
}
```

In this case, the execution of the function will end simply by exiting it.

But you can write like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetDiff(int start, int end)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (start >= end)
            yield break;
        yield return start;
        start++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Finish"); // note that this line will not be executed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Popped your code in a compiler, built, and reverse engineered back to C#, this came out:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static IEnumerable<int> GetDiff(int start, int end)
{
    while (start < end)
    {
        yield return start;
        start++;
    }
}
```

*I used LINQPad 5 and ILSpy for LINQPad.*

No yield break there. Alright, alright, that still has sugar... let us translate to C# 1.0. This is how the code looks like:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[IteratorStateMachine(typeof(<GetDiff>d__1))]
public static IEnumerable<int> GetDiff(int start, int end)
{
    <GetDiff>d__1 <GetDiff>d__ = new <GetDiff>d__1(-2);
    <GetDiff>d__.<>3__start = start;
    <GetDiff>d__.<>3__end = end;
    return <GetDiff>d__;
}
```

It is creating an instance of a hidden anonymous class `<GetDiff>d__1`, sets its `start` and `end` attributes and return it. We will get back to the `-2` we pass to its constructor.

The following is the same code above, except it is in IL:

```
.method public hidebysig static 
    class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<int32> GetDiff (
        int32 start,
        int32 end
    ) cil managed 
{
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IteratorStateMachineAttribute::.ctor(class [mscorlib]System.Type) = (
        01 00 17 55 73 65 72 51 75 65 72 79 2b 3c 47 65
        74 44 69 66 66 3e 64 5f 5f 31 00 00
    )
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2052
    // Code size 22 (0x16)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldc.i4.s -2
    IL_0002: newobj instance void UserQuery/'<GetDiff>d__1'::.ctor(int32)
    IL_0007: dup
    IL_0008: ldarg.0
    IL_0009: stfld int32 UserQuery/'<GetDiff>d__1'::'<>3__start'
    IL_000e: dup
    IL_000f: ldarg.1
    IL_0010: stfld int32 UserQuery/'<GetDiff>d__1'::'<>3__end'
    IL_0015: ret
} // end of method UserQuery::GetDiff
```

---

The class `<GetDiff>d__1` looks like this:

```
// <GetDiff>d__1
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <GetDiff>d__1 : IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable, IEnumerator<int>, IDisposable, IEnumerator
{
    private int <>1__state;

    private int <>2__current;

    private int <>l__initialThreadId;

    private int start;

    public int <>3__start;

    private int end;

    public int <>3__end;

    int IEnumerator<int>.Current
    {
        [DebuggerHidden]
        get
        {
            return <>2__current;
        }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        [DebuggerHidden]
        get
        {
            return <>2__current;
        }
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    public <GetDiff>d__1(int <>1__state)
    {
        this.<>1__state = <>1__state;
        <>l__initialThreadId = Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId;
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
    }

    private bool MoveNext()
    {
        switch (<>1__state)
        {
        default:
            return false;
        case 0:
            <>1__state = -1;
            break;
        case 1:
            <>1__state = -1;
            start++;
            break;
        }
        if (start < end)
        {
            <>2__current = start;
            <>1__state = 1;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool IEnumerator.MoveNext()
    {
        //ILSpy generated this explicit interface implementation from .override directive in MoveNext
        return this.MoveNext();
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    void IEnumerator.Reset()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    IEnumerator<int> IEnumerable<int>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        <GetDiff>d__1 <GetDiff>d__;
        if (<>1__state == -2 && <>l__initialThreadId == Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId)
        {
            <>1__state = 0;
            <GetDiff>d__ = this;
        }
        else
        {
            <GetDiff>d__ = new <GetDiff>d__1(0);
        }
        <GetDiff>d__.start = <>3__start;
        <GetDiff>d__.end = <>3__end;
        return <GetDiff>d__;
    }

    [DebuggerHidden]
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Int32>.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Let us start at the constructor:

```
public <GetDiff>d__1(int <>1__state)
{
    this.<>1__state = <>1__state;
    <>l__initialThreadId = Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId;
}
```

We are storing in `<>1__state` the value we passed. Remember that was a `-2` (`new <GetDiff>d__1(-2)`). We are also storing the id of the calling thread.

The first thing the client `foreach` loop will do is call `GetEnumerator` on the retuned `IEnumerable<int>`. There is some logic there:

```
[DebuggerHidden]
IEnumerator<int> IEnumerable<int>.GetEnumerator()
{
     <GetDiff>d__1 <GetDiff>d__;
    if (<>1__state == -2 && <>l__initialThreadId == Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId)
    {
        <>1__state = 0;
        <GetDiff>d__ = this;
    }
    else
    {
        <GetDiff>d__ = new <GetDiff>d__1(0);
    }
    <GetDiff>d__.start = <>3__start;
    <GetDiff>d__.end = <>3__end;
    return <GetDiff>d__;
}
```

It is checking that the consumer is the same thread and that state has not changed (from the original `-2`) if that holds, it returns itself. Otherwise, it returns a clone. That means that if `GetEnumerator` is called from another thread or is called by the same thread after iteration has started, the returned `IEnumerator<int>` starts from the beginning (as it should).

Also notice that `GetEnumerator` changes the state to `0`. That is important.

Now, pay attention to the `MoveNext` method. It is an state machine equivalent to your code:

```
private bool MoveNext()
{
    switch (<>1__state)
    {
    default:
        return false;
    case 0:
        <>1__state = -1;
        break;
    case 1:
        <>1__state = -1;
        start++;
        break;
    }
    if (start < end)
    {
        <>2__current = start;
        <>1__state = 1;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

On the first call, state is `0`, the code enters the `switch` and sets the state to `-1`.

After the `switch`, the code checks if `start < end`. This is the check to see if it will enter your `while` loop. If it does not enter, it just returns `false` and it is done. If it enters, you `yield return start`, so it puts `start` in `<>2__current`, changes the state to `1` and returns `true`. Since it returned `true`, the client `foreach` reads the current value, does a loop and calls `MoveNext` again...

Second time around, it enters the switch since it is on state `1`, then it changes the state to `-1` again, and does `start++` which was your next line... now your `while` loops, meaning that we have to check `start < end`, and that is what it does after the `switch`. If that conditional is still `true`, it will put the new value of `start` in `<>2__current`, change the state and return `true`.

The client `foreach` loop will keep consuming the iterator until the conditional does not hold anymore... then `MoveNext` returns `false`, this tells the `foreach` that the iterator is done and the loop ends.

---

For reference the following code is equivalent to a `foreach` loop ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-foreach-statement)):

```
{
    E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator();
    try {
        while (e.MoveNext()) {
            V v = (V)(T)e.Current;
            embedded_statement
        }
    }
    finally {
        ... // Dispose e
    }
}
```

---

So, what does `yield break;` do? In this case, nothing. `yield break;` is used to indicate that the state machine should end (`MoveNext` returns `false`), however the state machine will end there anyway because it is the end of the method. As consequence, you will only find `yield break;` useful (and meaningful) when it is not at the end of the method. For example see [Stanislav Molchanovsky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55662620/402022).

Furthermore, I would also argue that adding `yield break;` does not contribute to maintainability or readability of the code.

Comment: thanks, great answer! so compiler return `MoveNext = false` for you and we don't need to `yield break` explicitly in the end of the method